# Headers already sent error in Magento Contact form

Tags: http-headers, magento-1.7, contact-form

I am displaying a contact from in a fixed div in my footer so that it will show up on all pages. It does. When i click on a 'contact' button it will load the contact form through AJAX. For that I have created a new action in the indexController of Magento's default contact module. In that action i am echoing a block which calls my custom form that i am using to show on all pages.

```
public function quickcontactAction(){
    echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('contacts/formquick.phtml')->toHtml();           
}
```

So basically there are two files in the template of contacts module, form.phtml and formquick.phtml. From the footer i am calling the action which calls the formquick.phtml file which calls to indexController.php's post action method.
Now my problem is when i try to submit the form from that fixed div in footer it generates a system log which says headers are already sent.

```
HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Response\Http.php:52
[1] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\lib\Zend\Controller\Response\Abstract.php:766
[2] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Response\Http.php:83
[3] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php:188
[4] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php:354
[5] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\app\Mage.php:683
[6] C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-5.3.8.0\www\magento\index.php:81
</pre>
```

I am sensing there is something to do with the whole contact form loop but can't quite figure out how to solve. Also after form is submitted it redirects to contact page since that's how it is set in the controller but I want it to stay on the same page. Can anyone guide me please? I just need to load a different contact form through AJAX. If there's some better way to do then it's fine too. Anyone?

Comment: I have checked for extra white spaces at the end of the file but there are none. So someone please give me some solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it myself. I was echoing a block inside my controller action. So removed that and instead rendered the layout like this

```
public function quickcontactAction(){
    $this->loadLayout()->renderLayout();
}
```

and in my contacts.xml added a new block that called the contact form file.